# I need use ffimageloading with input:AdvancedEntry

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have this code and working no issue :

```
<input:AdvancedEntry Margin="0,10,0,0"
                            BorderColor="#D9DCDB"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            IconColor="LightGray"                                             
                            IconImage="icon_lock.png"
                            IsPassword="True"
                            Placeholder="{x:Static local:Strings.Password}"
                            Text="{Binding User.Password}"
                            TextColor="Black"
                            TextFontSize="18" />
```

I need to replace IconImage to this line :

```
 <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Source="resource://AppTest.Resources.ic_lock_24px.svg"/>
```

It say error and input:AdvancedEntry not supported ffimageloadingsvg I need a solution for that or any hint can help me to achieve this code as well .

Comment: what is `AdvancedEntry`?  Is that a nuget package or a custom control?  Do their docs say that they support SVG icons?

Comment: This is plugin.inputkit.shared.control.advancedentry ,I do not know but I'm asking if I need to use with it .

Comment: unless it was specifically designed to work with FFImageLoading I don't think it is going to do what you want

Comment: Okay thanks , I will try to customize it .

Comment: I agree that you can't replace IconImage to ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage.   You can change the size of the image to make the text field smaller or larger.